# C# - click buttons and perform actions in external application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create C# Windows Form App that will insert data from CSV file to Sage 50 accounts application. I already created button that automatically sends login and password to application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string login = "user";
            string pass = "password";
            IntPtr WindowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Logon");
            if (WindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window doesn't exist");
                return;
            }
            SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait(login);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait(pass);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr WindowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Sage 50 Accounts Professional");
            SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use SendMessage function to click button in Sage application and also used Spy++ to get the button ID, but I'm not sure if I used it right:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr WindowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Sage 50 Accounts Professional");
            SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle);

            const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
            const int btn = 0x12EEA720;
            SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_COMMAND, btn, 0);
        }
```

What should I do to make it work? How can I send actions to chosen buttons/labels etc.? I searched in MS docs but this seems unclear to me.

I wanted my app to click this button:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure Sage has an API. You really should use that instead.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted to create app like this and use similar code later with other external applications (that don't have API) as I need them to automate my work. This Sage automation will be only a part of whole app.

Comment: There are tools (the current buzz word is Robotic Process Automation) that do this. I expect it will be a very long, difficult and error prone endeavor for you to write this yourself.

Comment: Hi Ania, as I see it, you need to activate window of ext app and send key strokes right. Am I missing anything else ?

Comment: @Clint yes, I need to send key strokes and click buttons but I don't know how to show my app which textbox in external app is the target or how to click chosen button. I edited my question to show which button I'm trying to click from my C# app.

Comment: @Ania, can you kindly confirm, if the solution below helped you out, if yes, please click on green tick to mark it as resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to make it work? How can I send actions to chosen
>   buttons/labels etc.? I searched in MS docs but this seems unclear to
>   me.

In your program you're sending message WM_COMMAND to "Sage 50 Accounts Professional window" and not a particular UI control such as a button or label

**From MSDN**

> **SendMessage()** Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage
>   function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does
>   not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

#### Key primary steps involved in going about spy++ automation

- Identify your application type, for investigating 64 bit apps you would launch spyxx_amd64.exe else you can use the regular spyxx.exe

- First Investigate the Window Handler of the **UI control**, you wish to send message to. I have used spy++ to investigate **button** control and result in image below
  [image: InvestigateButtonControl]

- Identifying the value of `lpszWindow` which is the 4th parameter for `FindWindowEx()` This can be tricky, there are times when you might not know the real button name, Some times it can be prefixed with an `&ButtonText` and other times it might not something different.
  In the above example, value of lpszWindow for `Button` is `ButtonText`

- Identifying the value of 2nd Param of `SendMessage()` which is `uInt32 Msg` that can be found from Spy++. As per image below its value is `0x0201`

- Identifying the value of 1st Param which is `Window hwnd Handle` of the control whom you want to send the message to

---

#### Solution :

- **Console App** that interacts with the WinForm Apps, ***(See Inline Comments in the code)***

```
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{

    public class Program 
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam,IntPtr lParam);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hwndParent, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5; //message for Click which is a constant
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201; //message for Mouse down
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202; // message for Mouse up

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


           //Get the MainWindow handle of the Form1 APp
            var windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Form1");

            //Using the Handle To Bring it to foreground
            SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);



           //Getting the ButtonHandle for the different UI Controls, last param is the ControlText displayed on the UI 
            var btnHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, "ButtonText");
            var txtHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, "TextBoxText");
            var lblHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, "LabelText");
            var chkBoxHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, "CheckBoxText");

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);



            //With the UI handle identified, we are passing the message(2nd param) that we have identified from Spy++
            SendMessage(btnHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            SendMessage(chkBoxHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);//ButtonDown
            SendMessage(chkBoxHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);//ButtonUp
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            SendMessage(txtHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            SendMessage(txtHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            SendMessage(lblHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            SendMessage(lblHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);




        }

    }
}
```

---

- Simple **Winform App** to recreate the problem

**WinForm Form1.cs**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        int counter = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            textBox1.Text = counter++.ToString();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You got me !!");
        }

    }
}
```

**WinForm Form1.Designer.CS**

```
using System.Drawing;
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(178, 84);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(318, 200);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "ButtonText";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(641, 34);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.textBox1.Text = "TextBoxText";
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 25);
            this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 21);
            this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.checkBox1.Text = "CheckBoxText";
            this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(615, 132);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.label1.Text = "LabelText";
            this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);

            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }
        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

The program would click `Button` then tick `CheckBox` then selects `TextBox` and then clicks `Label`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will check your solution and let know if it works

Comment: @Clint thanx for your answer.I searched two days for that. But all the solutions are not detailed, half or not working. But your is the best one. I tried and work fine. I am surprised owner of subject did not mark as solution. Also noone gives anypoint. First was is mine. Thanx you so much again.

Comment: @Gokhan, I'm glad it helped you and I'm sure you will help someone in the future. Have a nice day!